# jq: filter input based on if key ends with specified string

Tags: json, filter, key, jq

I get this JSON data mess in and I need to extract the list of types:

```
{
  "token/": {
    "accessor": "auth_token_909d6a81",
    "config": {
      "default_lease_ttl": 0,
      "max_lease_ttl": 0
    },
    "description": "token based credentials",
    "local": false,
    "seal_wrap": false,
    "type": "token"           <-- I need to extract this value ...
  },
  "userpass/": {
    "similar_to": {
      "above": null
    },
    "description": "",
    "local": false,
    "seal_wrap": false,
    "type": "userpass"        <-- ... and this one
  },
  "request_id": "f2a4c135-f699-f29d-ca7c-3320dce0a550",
  "more_keys": "more_values",
  "data": {
    "more_data": {
      "even_more_data": "snipped"
    }
  },
  "you_get_the": "idea"
}
```

Sorry for the inline comments messing up the data when copying & pasting, but that seems the best way to clarify my goal:
For all root keys that end with `/`, I need the value of `.type`, so that the final result for the above example is `token userpass`.

I managed to create a working filter for the root keys:

```
host:~ user$ jq -r '. | keys[] | endswith("/")' <<< "${json_data}"
false
false
false
true
true
false
```

and I can use that filter to get only the wanted keys, but that is the keys alone and not the entire data structures underneath them:

```
host:~ user$ jq -r '. | keys[] | select(. | endswith("/"))' <<< "${json_data}"
token/
userpass/
```

I just can't seem to put this all together...

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '. as $o | keys_unsorted[] | select(endswith("/")) | $o[.].type' file.json
```

The output:

```
token
userpass
```

Comment: As soon as you do it right, it works  Thanks for the quick help! 

Answer (score 31):

`to_entries` is worth knowing about, not least because it often leads to easy-to-read (variable-free) pipelines, as here:

```
to_entries[] | select(.key|endswith("/")) | .value.type
```

Comment: Another day, another problem - your post was the answer. Worth knowing about indeed! 